# SQL :How to get the latest/max Id from the select query using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to execute the SQL select query using the pyodbc library but not getting the way to find the last or the max row ID from the Database.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r"Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}; Server=XXXX; Database=sampleDb; Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select Id, text from Table1 where dataexecuted IS NULL AND text is not null")
newdata = cursor.fetchall()
for l in newdata:
   rowId = l.Id
   rowId = max(rowId)
   print(rowId)
```

I Have also tried to find the data in this way but Shows error

```
select max(Id) as lastid, Id, text from Table1 where dataexecuted IS NULL AND text is not null
```

Comment: Are you sure whether you want the latest or the maximum? They’re not necessarily the same, especially if you have multiple users on the same database.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the maximum ID value then you can do this in a very simple query:

```sql
SELECT Max(Id) AS maximum_id
FROM   Table1
WHERE  dataexecuted IS NULL
AND    text IS NOT NULL
;
```

You can then use `cursor.fetchone()` to obtain the single row resultset.

**UPDATE:** alternative to `fetchone()` is `fetchval()` for single, scalar values.

```py
maxid = cursor.execute("select max(Id) from Table1;").fetchval()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the exact requirement is not clear from the question. But if you just want to resolve the error and find the max value of Id, then changing your `sql` query should help.

```
--removed Id, text columns from select -- this query will give absolute max value of ID
select max(Id) as lastid from Table1 where dataexecuted IS NULL AND text is not null 

-- added Id, text in group by -- this query will give max Id for each set of text column value.
select max(Id) as lastid, Id, text from Table1 where dataexecuted IS NULL AND text is not null group by Id, text
```

which query to use depends on your requirement.

And there is no need to iterate result set using `for` loop to find `max` values or any `aggregate` values from database that is not a very efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

To get the maximum id from database use the following:

```
cursor.execute("select max(id) from Table1 where dataexecuted IS NULL AND text is not null;")
result = cursor.fetchone()
conn.commit;
```

The *result* will have the structure *(id,)*. You can select it by *result[0]*.

If you write

```
cursor.execute("select max(id) from Table1 where dataexecuted IS NULL AND text is not null;").fetchone()
```

you'll get probably *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'*, because the reture object of *execute* is none.